# App crashes when MediaPlayer is release() in onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm a student doing a project for my school. I'm trying to play a sound when my app displays an alert but it crashes after a while. *My program is to grab certain data from a web server at intervals so it's updated and shows alert msg based on anomalies configured*

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button speed;
private TextView result;
private TextView sSpeed;
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
MediaPlayer mpAlarm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    sSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sSpeed);
    speed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_button);
    speed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startTimer();
        }
    });
    mpAlarm = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
    View speedButton = this.findViewById(R.id.get_button);
    speedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton = this.findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitButton = this.findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.get_button:
            startTimer();
            getWebsite();
            break;
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
            stopTimer();
            finish();
            break;
    }
}

private void getWebsite(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Start_Stop_buttons_UTF8.html").get();
                // Elements element = doc.getElementsByTag("p");
                Elements element = doc.select("p");
                //String title = doc.title();
                builder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element tag : element){
                    builder.append("\n\n").append(tag.text());
                }
                /*for(Element speed: element){
                    element.toString();
                }*/

            }catch(IOException e){
                //e.printStackTrace();
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String a = builder.toString(); // parse data from html into new string
                    a = a.substring(a.indexOf(":")+1, a.indexOf("Control")).trim();//trim string content
                    String b = builder.toString();
                    b = b.substring(11,b.indexOf(":")+1).trim();
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a.subSequence(0,a.length()-1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    double speed = Double.parseDouble(a);//convert string into double
                    if (speed<1000){ //acceptable rate is 1000-1500
                        mpAlarm.start();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Alert!\nFan is too slow!\nPlease contact admin and fix issue.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("HTML text","too slow");
                    }
                    else if((speed> 1500)){
                        mpAlarm.start();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Alert!\nFan is too fast!\nPlease contact admin and fix issue.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("HTML text","too fast!");
                    }
                    else{
                        mpAlarm.release();
                    }


                    result.setText(a);
                    sSpeed.setText(b);

                }
            });
        }

    }).start();

}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mpAlarm.release();

}

public void startTimer(){
    if(timer != null) return;
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWebsite();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,2000,3000);
}

public void stopTimer(){
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;

    }
}
```

}

I tried removing mpAlarm.release() in the onCreate and it works but the sound isn't synchronized with the display when transitioned from an alerted display back to normal during testing, i.e. it keeps playing for awhile even when there's supposed to be no alert after the change.

```
else if((speed> 1500)){
                        mpAlarm.start();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Alert!\nFan is too fast!\nPlease contact admin and fix issue.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("HTML text","too fast!");
                    }

                    result.setText(a);
                    sSpeed.setText(b);
```

Error log:

```
    08-08 15:26:59.740 6219-6219/com.sp.i40project W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xaccccb20)
    08-08 15:26:59.740 6219-6219/com.sp.i40project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.sp.i40project, PID: 6219
                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1064)
                                                                 at com.sp.i40project.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**How do fix this issue or is there a better way to implement the features I want?**

p.s. I'm just testing my program by changing the values in my web server to show normal data and when alerted.

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs shown above.

Comment: The weird thing is that it only crashed when there's a transition from normal display to alerted msg